# How to use macro variable with derived value in PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I have a situation where I need to assign a table name with a macro variable whose value is derived from another macro variable.

However, the generated code in macro uses the derivation formula rather than the derived value itself.

```
    %macro testing;

    %let n=2;
    %let k=&n-1;
    %let opp=&k;

    PROC SQL;

    CREATE TABLE WORK.TABLE_&opp AS
    SELECT * from WORK.SOURCETABLE;

    QUIT;

    %mend;

    %testing
```

This resulted in error as the code generated

```
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "OPP".
34          WORK.TABLE_2-1
                    _
                    22
                    200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error,
```

But I am expecting the resultant table will be named as WORK.TABLE_1 instead of WORK.TABLE_2-1.

So how can I force SAS to identify variable opp=1 rather than opp=2-1?

Thank you

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000208971.htm - you can read up about %eval here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using %eval as shown under:

```
 %macro testing;

    %let n=2;
    %let k=&n-1;
    %let opp=%eval(&k);

    PROC SQL;

    CREATE TABLE WORK.TABLE_&opp AS
    SELECT * from WORK.SOURCETABLE;

    QUIT;

    %mend;

    %testing
```

Comment: Yep, seems to do the trick. Need to read up more on macro functions. Thanks!

Comment: A macro variable is stored as a text string, so SAS doesn't recognise any calculation in a `%let` statement, unless a macro function is used.  I'm not sure why you have variables k and opp, as they take the same value (unless this is purely for example purposes).  You could put `%let k=%eval(&n-1)` to get the same answer

Comment: Just note that you need `SYSEVALF` if you are not performing integer operations